# Port forwarding to local ip is not working in windows server 2019

Tags: port-forwarding, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2019

I want to run Call Of Duty 4 host server.

First I install the windows server 2019 in Google cloud platform. 
After that I install the call of duty game server and run it is running on local ip `10.128.0.4:28960`
You can join game to this local ip address inside the server everything work perfect but I want to expose it for other world.

My server ip address is `34.67.221.157`

I follow these steps to forward port to local ip [Port Forward in windows server](http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/)

1. I make the ip address static `10.128.0.4`
2. Port forward using this command
   `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=10.128.0.4 listenport=28960 connectaddress=34.67.221.157 connectport=28960` __> command run successfully
3. After that I add this port into firewall
   `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”forwarded_CODport_28960” protocol=TCP dir=in localip=10.128.0.4  localport=28960 action=allow` __> command run successfully

After that I try to connect `34.67.221.157:28960` from my game but it's not also to connect

> Server connection timeout

Here is what it show after all these successful commands [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tafPN.jpg)

I'm new in windows server what step I miss please let me know

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the "listen" and "connect" parts the wrong way around at step 2 (see [this example](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-configure-port-forwarding-on-a-windows-10-pc), which states "if you want to route to port 8888 on the device with IP 192.168.0.1, you'd use these values for the "connectport" and "connectaddress" respectively").

Furthermore, I believe you used the incorrect IP (the "internal" IP instead of the "external"/public and open-to-the-Internet IP) at step 3.

Try this instead for step 2:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=34.67.221.157 listenport=28960 connectaddress=10.128.0.4 connectport=28960
```

This will ensure the server listens for traffic on `34.67.221.157:28960` (i.e. from the Internet) and "forwards" that traffic to `10.128.0.4:28960` (your internal server), which I believe was your intention. Note: You can also leave out `connectport` if it is the same as `listenport`, i.e. this will have the same result:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=34.67.221.157 listenport=28960 connectaddress=10.128.0.4
```

As for step 3, also use the other IP instead (notice I changed the IP for the `localip` parameter):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”forwarded_CODport_28960” protocol=TCP dir=in localip=34.67.221.157 localport=28960 action=allow
```

Remember to also undo the commands you ran earlier to remove the incorrect rules, especially the one from step 2:

```
netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenaddress=34.67.221.157 listenport=28960
```

Check out [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy) for the `netsh interface portproxy` commands here, which include the ones above and several more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).